# How can i disable reCAPTCHA on firebase when authenticating phone number?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I have been trying to disable reCAPTCHA on firebase in vain.
I set up SHA1 and SHA256 alright.
The issue came when i could not find android device verification API and it was replaced with Google Play Integrity API.
Anyway i enabled it but unexpectedly my app still took me to the reCAPTCHA page. I have looked up everywhere on the internet but am not getting a solution.
Does anybody understand this please to assist me.